# Comparing to paired categorical variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, python

I have a variable X with 100 samples, each is 1 (success) or 0 (failure)
Thereafter I perform somekind of manipulation, and recollect data, so I get 100 more samples that are 1 or 0,
How can I check for significane rise

Comment: Are you sure that it's paired? For example, does #53 in the first batch correspond to #53 in the second batch?

Comment: Yes, they are paired for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[McNemar's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) seems relevant here. You can basically summarize your data in a 2 X 2 table, indicating how many were 0/1 in each of iteration 0/1 of the test. This is the settings for McNemar's.

In Python, you can use [`statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.mcnemar`](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.mcnemar.html) from `statsmodels`.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
import numpy as np

from statsmodels.stats import contingency_tables

>>> contingency_tables.mcnemar(np.array([[50, 60], [50, 40]])).pvalue
0.39092745669950518

>>> contingency_tables.mcnemar(np.array([[50, 90], [50, 10]])).pvalue
0.00091311287400158204
```

Comment: Do you have an example on how to use this module in python? couldn't find an example, not even in the docs itself

Comment: @oren See update. You need to give it a 2 X 2 contingency table (see the Wikipedia entry), and it will return an object containing the statistic & pvalue.

Comment: I'll note that in R, the _mcnemar.test_ function can handle tables larger than 2 x 2.  Also, you can construct an exact test by binomial or multinomial test.  Details are here: http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_05.html .

Comment: @Ami Thanks a lot. I was not sure whether I should give table of counters or the row vector of the samples itself. So based on the wiki entry, here, [50, 60] is [cou(before_1_after_1) , cou(before_1_after_0)] and [40,40] is [cou(before_0_after_1), cou(before_0_after_0)] , right?

Comment: @oren No problem. That was not the example I wanted to give, though (typo), since, in your case, the rows & columns must each sum 10 100. In the above 2 examples, before is 50/50% A change to 60/40% is not very significant, but a change to 90/10% is.

Comment: @AmiTavory sorry for nagging but I failed to understand something: If I only give him the total number of 1's and 0's before and after, how can the test use the fact that samples are paired? 
For example, it won't notice the difference between the two following scenarios:

scenario A: 
before: 0 0 0 1 1
After : 1 0 0 1 1
scenario B:
before: 0 0 0 1 1 
after: 1 1 1 0 0
Even though they should probably have different outcome, taking into account that samples are paired.

Comment: @oren Consider [the example in the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test#Examples). Since it has a cell for before-present/after-present (for example), the pairing is there - to fill this in, you'd need to look at *pairs*, and ask how many had this attribute. If you'd only have *total* numbers for before and after, you couldn't fill it in. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ami That what I meant in my previous question, perhaps I wasn't clear. Actually, the rows corresponds to the wiki table - so [40 60] means 40 = number of before absent and after present and 60 = number of before absent and after absent? Or 40 = number of zeros after , 60 = number of ones after?
if the first answer, it makes sense :) If the latter, it doesn't..

Comment: @oren Your first interpretation seems right. Just to sync, this corresponds to the second row, if using the labels in the example in Wikipedia.

Comment: @oren No problem. All the best.